# python xml delete hostname from elements

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to delete elements that contains specific hostnames from a known list. 
I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree

please see the xml below:

```
<intermediate_model method="INTERMEDIATE" version="Revision: 1.1.2.9.2.4.14.12.10.1">
<creation_time />
<network_model>
    <host hostname="test-pc:WINS" os="Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1">
        <interface ip_address="1.1.1.1" />
    </host>
<network_model>
<creation_time />
```

How do I delete the element "host" that holds this "test-pc" using python? The idea is to delete all Elements that have a specific hostnames from a list

This is the list:

```
test-pc
a-pc
b-pc
```

Comment: *from a list* - post that list and extend your xml fragment with ending tags

Comment: Done, Thanks. The list can be changed, the idea is to have in that list the hostnames. I can create a csv file within all the hostnames, one name per line.

Comment: ok, can you extend your input to present also the nodes that should not be deleted? It'll be more pepresentative

Comment: you data is giving error..can you please paste correct xml